# How to access request in JspTags?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I want to call `request.getContextPath()` inside a JSP tag which extends `SimpleTagSupport`, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First get the [`PageContext`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html) by the inherited [`SimpleTagSupport#getJspContext()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/SimpleTagSupport.html#getJspContext%28%29) and then get the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) by [`PageContext#getRequest()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html#getRequest%28%29).

```
PageContext pageContext = (PageContext) getJspContext();  
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) pageContext.getRequest();
```

Comment: so it's possible to access the request inside a JspTag, but is it a good idea? It seems to me that is like your JSP tag could have hidden parameters that are not self evident as attributes are.

Comment: Exactly. As he said, he wants to use `getContextPath()`.